# How to solve the equation to get the reverse values?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Here is my original equation:

$Vc = \frac {(C-B)}{A}$
where Vc = Price obtained from the calculations,
C = Close Price,
$A = 0.2\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n (Hi - Li)}{n}$,
$B = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n \frac {(Hi + Li)}{2}}{n}$,
Where H = High Price and L = Low Price.

Now I tried reversing the equation as:

$C = \frac{(0.2 Vc\sum_{i=0}^n (Hi - Li)) + \sum_{i=0}^n \frac {(Hi + Li)}{2}}{n}$

Now coming to the problem, I am not able too retrieve my C price for the specific Vc price because whenever I tried I am not able to comprehend the values of the H and L because when I am tried to put a value of H or L it will keep changing and my regression keep growing. I am looking for a solution so that if I put a Vc value in the Equation I should get C value without me doing regression or checking.
Is it possible?

Comment: You want a formula for $C$ that just depends on $Vc$? How can such a thing be possible, when Vc also depends on all the Hi and Li?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes you are right. But if that is not the case than what could be the solution? I want to avoid regression if possible that is the biggest culprit I am facing.

Comment: If *what* is not the case? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay so in simple terms is there any solution that does not require a regression method too finding C using the Vc price?

Comment: I'll ask you again; how can there possibly be a way to find C using just Vc? The same value of Vc could correspond to infinitely many different values of C, depending on what the Hi and Li are.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So that means there is nothing can be done and I have to go with the regression that I am trying. Well, Thank you for the discussion.